# XACML Read resources

Tags: xacml

I'm trying to do a rule that allows access to any resource just when the action is read for every user. I have the doubt if I need to put something like **any** users like here

```
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule Permit #1">
    <Target>
        <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
                <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                    <AttributeValue 
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">any
                    </AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator 
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" 
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" 
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
                    </AttributeDesignator>
                </Match>
```

And then the action

```
 <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                    <AttributeValue 
                         DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read
                    </AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator 
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" 
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" 
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
                </Match>
```

Or maybe I can delete the first part and put directly the action because the resource is any.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to Match the action:

```
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule Permit #1">
  <Target>
    <AnyOf>
        <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                <AttributeValue 
                  DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                <AttributeDesignator 
                  AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"  
                  Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" 
                  DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" 
                  MustBePresent="true" />
            </Match>
        </AllOf>
    </AnyOf>
  </Target>
</Rule>
```

In this case, if and only if the action-id equals 'read', the Rule evaluates to Permit, **regardless of user or resource attributes**, in other words: for any user or resource. Beware that the final decision depends on the rule combining algorithm on your enclosing Policy (and possibly policy combining algorithm on your PolicySet if you have one). If you get something different, that's an issue with the XACML implementation.

Comment: Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it works for you.